# Circuit analysis of a spark gap

Tags: tesla-coil, spark

I am confused about the action of a spark gap. I realize the gap is breached when the voltage reaches a critical point. But what happens to the remainder of the voltage? 
[image]
In the attached circuit the power supply has 2000VAC 10mA 30KHz. The breakdown voltage on the neons is 90V. The capacitor is 874nF and L1 is 40microH.

Without the neons the full 2,000V (rectified DC) would appear accross C and L1 (L1 before C). With the neons would that be reduced to 90V? Would the neons fire at the same time? Will L1 resonate with C? It's a bit different to a tesla coil in that a tesla coil has just one spark gap between L1 and C and C is pumped up to the breakdown voltage of the spark gap. I don't think that would happen in this case as the neons would break down at the same time.

Comment: The neon lamps won't break down at the same time.  90V is the nominal break down.  Any individual lamp will break down a little above or below that voltage.

Comment: Only a limited current can flow through the lamps.  You can view them as a switch with a series resistor.  When they are switched on, they allow current to flow.  The voltage across the load then depends on the resistance (in this, resistance and impedance) of the load, and whatever effective resistance the neon lamp has.

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused about the action of a spark gap. I realize the gap is breached when the voltage reaches a critical point. But what happens to the remainder of the voltage?

Sparks gaps will fire when the voltage between its contacts reaches the breakdown voltage. Once it has fired, a large current can now flow between its contacts. When the breakdown condition occurs, a much lesser voltage is needed to ionize the gas between the two contacts of the spark gap, which allows it to hold conduction even at voltages lesser than the breakdown voltage. This voltage is called the holding voltage. When the voltage across the junction goes below the holding voltage of the spark gap, the spark gap will stop conducting. It will remain in this state until only when the breakdown voltage is attained across it again.

In this context, I guess what you mean by 'remaining voltage' is the voltage across capacitor C. The spark gap will fire at some voltage V0, and it will remain conducting until it drops below a holding voltage V1, then the capacitor will charge back up to V0 and the cycle continues.

> With the neons would that be reduced to 90V?

No. The striking voltage of most neons are around 70V, and the holding voltage is 55-60V. This means that when the neons strike on, a maximum voltage of 55 or so volts is across them. L1 will certainly pull the voltage down, and the voltage across the capacitor willo be limited to around 60V, not 90V. But I will not count on that either; your neons could easily be fried from that power input with no resistor.

> Would the neons fire at the same time?

No. All neons are unique in their characteristics. Some take a longer time to turn on, some take a shorter time to turn on. Nothing is perfect in this world.

> Will L1 resonate with C?

Yes.

> It's a bit different to a tesla coil in that a tesla coil has just one spark gap between L1 and C and C is pumped up to the breakdown voltage of the spark gap. I don't think that would happen in this case as the neons would break down at the same time.

In the ideal world, this can happen. I would encourage you try this circuit out with yourself. I would too, it seems interesting.

Neons as a spark gap is a horrible idea from the get go. These turn on with relatively high turn-on impedance(in kilo-ohms), and for spark gaps, you'd usually want turn-on impedances of less than a few ohms, in order to carry copious amounts of current to pulse a coil. But give it a try if it doesn't hurt you.

Comment: When the spark gap fires the gas between them ionizes and its resistance drops a lot making it a conductor. Where the voltage goes depends on the circuit.

Comment: Gas discharge tubes (including neon lamps) have two regions of operation - glow discharge at moderate voltage and arc discharge at high voltage. After the glow-to-arc transition, it becomes a spark gap and its resistance drops dramatically to near zero.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen them used in lightning simulator. A bunch of capacitors are connected in series via spark gaps. They are shunted with a relative high value of resistance. The capacitors are then charged (in parallel because of the resistors). When a HV pulse is applied to one of the spark gaps it conducts placing two capacitors in series, the higher voltage causes it to ark the next gap until all are conducting, the end is where the charge is discharged. Spacing of these spark gaps is critical. Remember during the arc the gas between the electrodes ionizes and becomes a great conductor. This is one of many tests use to validate high voltage insulators such as used on HV power lines. Neon lamps have been used for this purpose since roughly the beginning of vacuum tubes.